# Dynamically pass component markup to Vue instance

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am building some software currently which will allow users to drop a HTML snippet into web pages and my VueJS stack will render blog posts dynamically.

I am trying to find a way to dynamically render component markup into a given `<div>` without declaring the Vue component markup within that `<div>` - to avoid confusion for customers.

This is an example of **working** code:

```html
<div id="live-blogs" v-cloak>
    <live-blog
        v-for="blog in blogs"
        :key="blog.id"
        :title="blog.title"
    ></live-blog>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('live-blog', {
    props: ['id', 'title'],
    template: '<div class="lb-entry">{{ title }}</div>',
});

const liveBlogs = new Vue({
    el: '#live-blogs',
    data: {
        blogs: [],
    },
    methods: {
        getLiveBlogs: function() {
            request.get('/read/' + id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    liveBlogs.blogs = response.data.data;
                })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getLiveBlogs();
    }
});
```

**What I would like to do**

I'd like to be able to strip out the component markup so my clients only have to copy and paste the following code. I am likely to add more components and functionality and don't want this embed growing in size.

Once the target `<div>` is detected, the javascript should handle the dynamic registration and rendering of component data.

```html
<div id="live-blogs"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file/app.js"></script>
```

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried passing the component markup via `this.$el.innerHTML = componentMarkup` but it hasn't worked.

Is this possible using VueJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is move the template from the DOM into the main component as a string template. As long as there is a `<div id="live-blogs"></div>` somewhere on the page, it'll just work.

```es6
Vue.component('live-blog', {
  props: ['id', 'title'],
  template: '<div class="lb-entry">{{ title }}</div>',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#live-blogs',
  template: `
<div>
  <live-blog
    v-for="blog in blogs"
    :key="blog.id"
    :title="blog.title"
  />
</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getLiveBlogs() {
      request.get('/read/' + id)
        .then(response => {
          this.blogs = response.data.data;
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getLiveBlogs();
  },
});
```

Comment: The bards will write songs about you. Thank you very much!